# 502 error not showing up in nginx error.log

Tags: nginx, http-status-codes

I am getting a 502 error when I try to access a path that uses `proxy_pass`. I checked `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, but the 502 error doesn't show up.

How do I debug this error if it isn't being logged?

---

Here's what my site config looks like(in sites-available):

```
upstream php-handler {
  server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/www.example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/www.example.com.key;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

  root /var/www/example.com/;
  index index.html index.php;

  client_max_body_size 500M;
  fastcgi_buffers 64 4k;
  gzip on;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }

  }

  location /apps/myApp/ {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:3030;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
location /apps/myApp/ {
  proxy_pass https://localhost:3030;
}
```

Should be this:

```
location /apps/myApp/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;
}
```